# Mt4 Probability Script

Tags: python-2.7, probability, forecasting, metatrader4, forex

I'm fairly new to `python`

I have made a simple script that imports price feeds from **`mt4`**

My idea / Project is to turn this into some sort of a probability indicator, that is giving the probability, besides the bid and ask,
for example:

```
TIME/                BID             ASK
USD/CADD     22:19   1.30451 60%^    1.30D39 40%v
```

and the probability is changing within specific period, i.e for example 1hr period, so every hour it will give a new probability of the direction

It is looking for two patterns: A, B,

Pattern A represents a bullish pattern

Pattern B represents a bearish pattern

basically looking for how strong is the probability A or B reoccurring
out of the two which has a higher chance of reoccurring,

Here is where I am stuck

I have no idea how to put that together...

Here is what I have so far:

```js
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

from pandas.io.data       import DataReader
from sklearn.ensemble     import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.lda          import LDA
from sklearn.metrics      import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.qda          import QDA
from sklearn.svm          import LinearSVC, SVC

import dde_client as ddec
import time

QUOTE_client = ddec.DDEClient('MT4', 'QUOTE')

symbols = ['USDCAD', 'GOLD','EURUSD', 'SILVER', 'US30Cash',  ]
for i in symbols:
    QUOTE_client.advise(i)


def Get_quote():
 while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Symbol\tDATE\t\tTIME\tBID\tASK"
    for i in symbols:
        current_quote = QUOTE_client.request(i).split(" ")
        day, _time, bid, ask = (current_quote[0], current_quote[1],
                            current_quote[2], current_quote[3])
        print i + ":\t" + day + "\t" + _time +"\t" +bid+ "\t" + ask
        break
        time.sleep(1)
        return Get_quote()
        continue


    def create_lagged_series(cuurent_quote,start_time, end_time, lags=1):
      ts = DataReader(cuurent_quote,symbols,
                    start_time-datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
                    end_time
                    )
      tslag = pd.DataFrame(index=ts.index)
      ts['Today'] = ts['Adj Close']
      tslag["Volume"] = ts["Volume"]
      for i in xrange(0, lags):
         tslag["Lag%s" % str(i+1)] = ts["Adj Close"].shift(i+1)

      tsret = pd.DataFrame(index=tslag.index)
      tsret["Volume"] = tslag["Volume"]
      tsret["Today"] = tslag["Today"].pct_change()*100.0

      for i in xrange(0, lags):
             if (abs(x) < 0.0001):
              tsret["Today"][i] = 0.0001

      for i in xrange(0,lags):
            tsret["Lag%s" % str(i+1)] = \
            tslag["Lag%s" % str(i+1)].pct_change()*100.0

      tsret["Direction"] = np.sign(tsret["Today"])
      tsret = tsret[tsret.index >= start_time]

      return tsret

      if __name__ == "__main__":
         snpert = create_lagged_series(len('GOLD', Get_quote(), 1))
         X = snpret[["Lag1","Lag2"]]
         y = snpret["Direction"]
         start_test = cuurernt_quote


         X_train = X[X.index < start_test]
         X_test = X[X.index >= start_test]
         y_train = y[y.index < start_test]
         y_test = y[y.index >= start_test]
         print "Hit Rates/Confusion Matrices:\n"
         models = [ ( "LR",   LogisticRegression() ),
                    ( "LDA",  LDA() ),
                    ( "QDA",  QDA() ),
                    ( "LSVC", LinearSVC() ),
                    ( "RSVM", SVC( C            = 1000000.0,
                                   cache_size   = 200,
                                   class_weight = None,
                                   coef0        = 0.0,
                                   degree       = 3,
                                   gamma        = 0.0001,
                                   kernel       = 'rbf',
                                   max_iter     = -1,
                                   probability  = False,
                                   random_state = None,
                                   shrinking    = True,
                                   tol          = 0.001,
                                   verbose      = False
                                   )
                      ),
                    ( "RF",   RandomForestClassifier( n_estimators = 1000,
                                                      criterion    = 'gini',
                                                      max_depth         = None,
                                                      min_samples_split = 2,
                                                      min_samples_leaf  = 1,
                                                      max_features      = 'auto',
                                                      bootstrap         = True,
                                                      oob_score         = False,
                                                      n_jobs            = 1,
                                                      random_state      = None,
                                                      verbose           = 0
                                                      )
                      )
                    ]

    # Iterate through the models
      for m in models:

        # Train each of the models on the training set
                 m[1].fit(X_train, y_train)


                 pred = m[1].predict(X_test)


                 print "%s:\n%0.3f" % (m[0], m[1].score(X_test, y_test))
                 print "%s\n" % confusion_matrix(pred, y_test)
```

Here is just my **`MT4`** price feed script on its own:

```js
import dde_client as ddec
import time

__author__ = 'forex Ticker'

print __author__


QUOTE_client = ddec.DDEClient('MT4', 'QUOTE')

symbols = ['USDCAD', 'GOLD','EURUSD', 'SILVER', 'US30Cash',  ]
for i in symbols:
    QUOTE_client.advise(i)



while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Symbol\tDATE\t\tTIME\tBID\tASK"
    for i in symbols:
        current_quote = QUOTE_client.request(i).split(" ")
        day, _time, bid, ask = (current_quote[0], current_quote[1],
                            current_quote[2], current_quote[3])
        print i + ":\t" + day + "\t" + _time +"\t" +bid+ "\t" + ask
        break
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate how do you get the quotes from MT4? I'm not understanding how do you connect the python script to MT4 to get the data.

Comment: using a custom module to connect to mt4 DDE  server:

Comment: http://fxgears.com/forum/index.php?topic=582.0 here is more information on how to set it up , would you be willing to help me out with this question,?

Answer (score 2):

As to fixing your algorithm I suggest that rather than doing it from scratch and hacking various libraries together, start from a working example and modify it to your liking. You don't have to understand it completely, but you need something to start with.

I would even abstract away the MT4 and quotes reading logic, and just have some test numbers (fake or sampled) in a CSV or TXT file. Start form a working example that can recognize A and B patterns in this file. Having that define how your own algorithm is different and try to adjust it.

When it's working the final step is the MT4 integration. It looks like the DDE server is only meant for data export, but not for building an indicator. Consider this alternative framework: linking [MT4 to Python](http://www.nquotes.net/metatrader-with-python). Not only you can build an on-chart indicator with it, but also perform automatic trading using your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### Q: How to put that together...?
 A: Have a Realistic Plan - best before one puts the money on table.
 That can save you
from even starting to do a nonsense
 or
from aiming at non-realistic targets.

No one would be harmed, if plan is the first working document elaborated and agreed by all parties involved on **HOW** the "*great and cool new disruptive vision*" **WILL BE CREATED**.

Organise your further work in steps + always add budget controls, be it in `[man*weeks]` or `[k$]`, one is willing to spend on items.

**One ought be able to decide on the feasibility and surviveability of the initially great & cool idea.**

Plan carefully inside the principal phases, both on the `MQL4/5` side, `python` and other components:

- `X [man*weeks]` on [System Integration Architecture],
- `Y [man*weeks]` on [Integration Model Design],
- `Z [man*weeks]` on [Integration Model Prototype],
- `U [man*weeks]` on [Integration Model Testing],
- `V [man*weeks]` on [Integration Model Release],
- `W [man*weeks]` on [Integration Model Production Ecosystem]
- `S [man*weeks]` on [Design Cycles on finding best Predictions Model]
- `T [man*weeks]` on [Design Cycles on finding good Trading Strategies for Predictions]

---

### Items not to be forgotten to overcome in the early architecture decisions:

**0)** Forget to use `MQL4/5` **examples**, you put yourself at risk into sub-millisecond domain battle with **hundreds of millions USD** in fight and motion
**1)** Forget to use **`Custom Indicator`** in MQL4/5 MetaTrader Terminal ( blocking )
**2)** Forget to use **`DDE`** integration, some O/S do not support it at all
**3)** Forget to use **`pandas`** ( even for any AI/ML-model prototyping ) as nanoseconds matter a lot in ML-process, pandas is a great toy, but not for the performance a real-world trading needs for ML-model tuning.
**4)** Forget to use start-end logic, the AI/ML-engines have to be separate, in order to efficiently train/validate/test for their best generalisation abilities in vast HyperPARAM state-spaces.
**`for m in models:`** can be in the source-code, but not in the reality. One instrument may take ( and does take ) about a few tens of **`[CPU-core*days]`** runtimes in parameter optimisation on COTS-hardware, so **count with realistic numbers here, for proper budgeting of each of the [S]+[T] cycles.**

---

### Epilogue:

> Anyway a smart Programme, if approved as financially feasible. May like other posts on Low-latency MT4-AI/ML-integration for **[algorithmic-trading](/questions/tagged/algorithmic-trading)**.